# how to add events to an appended element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image

**this is my code** :

```
function getChannelInfo(){ 
var name;
    var status;
    var logo;
    var game;
    var url;channels.forEach(function(channel){
function API(type,name){
  return 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/'+type+'/'+name+'?client_id=pd57d4ktf8rjarn9q3qgtv4owbr5q0';
};
$.getJSON(API("streams",channel),function(data){
    if(data.stream!==null){
       name=data.stream.channel.display_name;
       status=data.stream.channel.status;
       logo=data.stream.channel.logo;
       game=data.stream.channel.game;
       url=data.stream.channel.url;
    $("<div class='col-md-3 text-center'><a class='link'href='"+url+"' target='_blank'><img class='active' src="+logo+"></a><divclass='info'><h1 id='name' class='name'>"+name+"</h1><h2 class='game'>"+game+"</h2><h3 class='status'>"+status+"</h3></div></div>").appendTo('#channelsOn');
        } else {
$.getJSON(API("channels",channel),function(data1){
       name=data1.display_name;
       status="";
       logo=data1.logo;
       game="";
       url=data1.url;
var newContent = $("<div class='col-md-3 text-center offline'><aclass='link' href='"+url+"' target='_blank'><img class='noactive' src="+logo+"></a><div class='info'><h1 class='name'>"+name+"</h1><h2 class='game'>"+game+"</h2><h3 class='status'>"+status+"</h3></div></div>").appendTo("#channelsOff");
});
       }
});
  });
};
$(document).ready(function(){
  getChannelInfo();
 $('#channelsOn').on('mouseenter','img',function() {
   $('.info').animate({opacity:'1'});
 });
   $('#channelsOn').on('mouseout','img',function() {
   $('.info').animate({opacity:'0'});
});
  $('#channelsOff').on('mouseenter','img',function() {
   $('.info').animate({opacity:'1'});
 });
   $('#channelsOff').on('mouseout','img',function() {
   $('.info').animate({opacity:'0'});
     });
});
});
```

how can i show the info of one channel with mouseenter the img without showing all the info from all the channels. in my code when im over one img, all the info from all the channels are shown

Comment: Hmmm - there seems to be a few issues with your code. I can show you in my answer but one piece I can't fix without more information is: where's the "channels" variable set? What does it contain?

Comment: @MacPrawn the channels come from an array var channels=["ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, so as I said in my comments, there are a few things wrong with your code - but I'll come back to this. First, your question.

The problem is that your mouseenter/mouseout events target *all* .info divs... You want to target only the .info div of the element being moused over. So instead of

```
$('.info').animate({opacity:'1'});
```

try

```
$(this).parents('.col-md-3.text-center').children('.info').animate({opacity:'1'});
```

"$(this)" in this context will refer to the img that triggered the event. You're then looking for the common container for that img and its .info div, (parents()) and then from that container finding the child ".info".

You'll also want to start with all the .info elements hidden - best way to do this is through css so there's no flashing when the page loads.

Finally, a few mistakes in your code that I noticed:

```
...<divclass='info'>... // should be <div class='info'>

function API(type,name){ // should be var API = function(type,name){
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `parents()` method and then selecting the `.info`.

Like this:

```
$(this).parents('div.col-md-3.text-center').find('.info').animate({opacity:'0'});
```